# Does closing a question on Meta cast an automatic downvote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, automatic-votes

I just closed three questions on Meta as off-topic, and at all three questions immediately got another downvote. Does closing a question on Meta cast an automatic downvote?

If so, when was this implemented? Also, was is implemented for other sites?

I know this used to happen, but I thought it was disabled.